# Finding the frequency of numbers in an array in R

Tags: r, frequency

I need to find frequency of numbers say 0:8. in an every column of matrix A of order mxn.

How can I do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: `table` is the function generally used to find frequencies. Please share a reproducible example for "input" and "output".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `MARGIN=2` to loop through the columns, subset the elements that are 0:8 (`x %in% 0:8`), convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as `0:8` and use `table` to get the frequency of elements.

```
apply(A, 2, function(x) table(factor(x[x %in% 0:8], levels=0:8)))
```

Or another option would be to `melt` the matrix and convert to `data.table` using `setDT`, subset 0:8 (`J(0:8)`) from the "value" column after the setting the "value" column as key (`setkey`), group by "Var2", change the "value" column to "factor" class and get the frequency with `table`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(melt(A)), value)[J(0:8), 
      as.list(table(factor(value, levels=0:8))), by= Var2]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
A <- matrix(sample(0:15, 10*20, replace=TRUE), ncol=10)
```